# Gnome 3.32.2 deadly freezes on ubuntu 19.04 when working in PHPStorm

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell, intellij

I don't know exactly what the problem is, in `phpstorm`, or `gnome-shell`, because writing here.

`gnome-shell` freezes, when I working in PHPStorm. 
But freeze staring after click on any buttons in phpstorm's popup windows(creating folder, checking todo list, review.., etc), like this:

[image: phpstorm popup window]

mouse can moving but nothing clickable.

`gnome-shell` process loads one logical kernel 100% and don't unfreezes.

after this I kill `gnome-shell` process (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or through virtual terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), login and run programs again..

Initially, after upgrading to 19.04 this problem was not, it appeared after 2-3 months.

Now, this problem happens only with working in phpstorm

I have:

- GPU: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- OS: Ubuntu 19.04 disco
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.0.0-22-generic
- GNOME Shell 3.32.2
- PHPStorm 2019.2(2019.1)

I tried:

- set default gnome theme
- disable all user `gnome-extensions`
- disable all plugins on `phpstorm`
- set default theme on `phpstorm`
- reinstall gnome-shell like: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell`
- reinstall `phpstorm`
- change nvidia drivers(390 proprietary, 430 open source, xorg, 418 proprietary)

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue, though with other Jetbrains programs. Datagrip and Rider are both triggering the same gnome-shell freeze. Excruciatingly annoying.

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 20, actually same issues was on Ubuntu 16, 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with the commands found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1834583/comments/20)

```
On Ubuntu 19.04 run the following command to fix it (downgrading):

sudo apt install \
    gir1.2-mutter-4=3.32.0+git20190410-1ubuntu1 \
    libmutter-4-0=3.32.0+git20190410-1ubuntu1 \
    mutter=3.32.0+git20190410-1ubuntu1 \
    mutter-common=3.32.0+git20190410-1ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.
I've fixed it literally 5mins ago after searching another day for a fix ;)

I've removed vmoptions file from ../config dir. 
Try this maybe this will help You.

Comment: Thanks! but in what certainly directory is the file located? I installed phpstorm by snap and see `.vmoptions` files only in `/snap/phpstorm/109/bin/` directory..

Comment: Okey, I find `phpstorm64.vmoptions` file in `~/.PhpStorm2019.2/config/` directory. I tried to remove this, aaand the problem don't solved :( but I noticed, that I can create folder, copy files. But problem happens, after popup with code review(when committing) has opened

Comment: I've also reinstalled phpstorm from snap:
1. remove phpstorm
2. install phpstorm
3. Open phpstorm, and import settings from last profile
4. Close phpstorm
5. remove vmoptions file
6. open phpstorm

I've had problems with VCS windows, update, commit etc. now it's gone.

Comment: I've tried this now, but it's don't help me..

Comment: 1) remove phpstorm `snap remove phpstorm` 2) remove all settings `~/snap/phpstorm` `~/.Phpstorm2019.2/` 3) `snap forget [snap phpstorm id]` 4) `snap install phpstorm` 5) create new projects 6) close phpstorm 7) remove `phpstorm64.vmoptions` file 8) open phpstorm and freeze with VCS windows again :( Thanks for help, anyway